# I can't understand anything in this sentence. Please help

Tags: translation, readings, definitions, comprehension

I'm still a beginner learning japanese, so I'm sorry if this is just a stupid question. I was reading a manga and a character says:

> だめ。シミが浮くとこ見てるから。

I can't understand what he means or what he's referring to...
I can understand the "だめ" part, but what about "シミ" and everything else?
Although, I would really appreciate if someone tells me the meaning of everything here. Thanks in advance! :)

CONTEXT UPDATE: There are two characters in the page. One of those two says "If you're going to touch me, do it properly". Then, the other one who's touching him, says "だめ。シミが浮くとこ見てるから。", and he goes away for a brief moment. That's everything I can't understand, the "シミが浮くとこ見てるから" part. And yes, he's saying "シミ" and "浮く". Maybe the artist wrote the words wrong? I think that's a possibility. Again, thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with "shimi"... is that a character's name, or  could it possibly be キミ？　also, are you sure 浮{う}く　is correct? It means "float", but without context I can't imagine what is floating.

Comment: 文脈がないと、どういう状況だか・・・

Comment: シミ means "stain", "spot". It may mean that she dropped a bit water on a stain on something like clothes and look at the stain floating on the surface. Anyway, we need more context

Comment: Out of curiosity, which manga/comic book is this? If you could tell us, we might be able to use the context to figure out the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: I edited the post with more context. Again, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: When you provide context, it would help a lot if you do so without translating it yourself, and instead provide the original Japanese.  Sometimes what is needed is not the meaning, but the actual words that were used beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

> 「だめ。シミが浮{う}くとこ見{み}てるから。」

Basically, that can only mean one thing unless it is said in an extremely ususual context that is beyond my imagination.

> One of those two says "If you're going to touch me, do it properly".

It would have been ***far better*** if you had just given the line in the original Japanese.

Anyway, 「シミ」 means "***skin spots***".

「シミが浮く」 is a fairly standard expression  meaning "***spots form (on one's skin)***".

「とこ」 is the informal form of 「ところ」.

Thus, the sentence in question means:

> "No!  'Coz I've seen spots forming on your skin!"

Unless you miscopied the line, it simply could not mean anything else as far as grammar and vocabulary are concerned.

The "No!" part would probably mean "No, I can't!"

If you feel this does not fit in the context, you will need to provide further context and an explanation of the situation, the relationship between these two persons, etc.

Comment: First of all, thanks for you help! I wanna say that I don't really get the "spots forming on your skin" part. If you need a more detailed context, here I go. There are two characters. The first one says "触るならもっとちゃんと..." while he's being touched in his crotch by the other one. Then, the one who's touching him says the line that I don't understand, while he's looking at him. These two seems to trust each other really much, because they're close friends and they do 'things' together. They've also been talking about their problems. I'll also say that the one who's touching the other is an artist.

Comment: I'll also leave here a screenshot from the dialogue. Hope that helps you too. Again, thanks for all your help! :) This kind of things helps me to improve my japanese! And you can tell me if you need a more more detailed context. LINK: https://i.imgur.com/2MllXB6.png

Comment: @Ryuusei-kun Could you show us the whole page?